# Upgrading data.. SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined, query was: INSERT INTO

Tags: magento2, sql

when I execute an insert sql command  inside 'UpgradeData.php' it gives me this error, can anyone tell me where is the problem here ?

```
 if(version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.2', '<')) {
            $query = "INSERT INTO authorization_rule(role_id,resource_id,permission) VALUES (:role_id,:ressource_id,:permission)";

            $setup->getConnection()->query(
                $query,
                [

                    ':role_id' => 5,
                    ':resource_id' => 'Magento_Sales::unhold',
                    //':priviliges' => null,
                    ':permission' => 'deny'
                ]
            );
            $setup->getConnection()->query(
                $query,
                [
                    ':role_id' => 3,
                    ':resource_id' => 'Magento_Sales::unhold',
                    //':priviliges' => null,
                    ':permission' => 'deny'


                ]
            );
        }
```

the error is :

> SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined, query was: INSERT INTO authorization_rule(role_id,resource_id,permission) VALUES (:role_id,:ressource_id,:permission)

Comment: what is version number in module.xml

Comment: it is 1.0.2 in the module @YasirLatif the context version is 1.0.2